# Pandas Turning multiple rows with different types into 1 row with multiple columns for each type

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given the following `df`,

```
Account contract_date   type    item_id quantity    price   tax net_amount
ABC123  2020-06-17  P   1409    1000    0.355   10  400
ABC123  2020-06-17  S   1409    2000    0.053   15  150
ABC123  2020-06-17  C   1409    500 0.25    5   180
ABC123  2020-06-17  S   1370    5000    0.17    30  900
DEF456  2020-06-18  P   7214    3000    0.1793  20  600
```

I would like to turn `df`, grouped by Account, contract_date and item_id. Then split the values of different types into different column. Intended results are as follows. I can do this with for loop/apply, but would like to seek for suggestion for groupby or pivot or any vectorized/pythonic solution to this. Intended results are as follows:

```
Account contract_date   item_id quantity_P  quantity_S  quantity_C  price_P price_S price_C tax_P tax_S tax_C   net_amount_P    net_amount_S    net_amount_C
ABC123  2020-06-17  1409    1000    2000    500 0.355   0.053   0.25    10  15  5   400 150 180
ABC123  2020-06-17  1370    0   5000    0   0   0.17    0   0   30  0   0   900 0
DEF456  2020-06-18  7214    3000    0   0   0.1793  0   0   20  0   0   600 0   0
```

*Although it looks a bit off for the alignment, you may copy the `df` and use `df = pd.read_clipboard()` to read the table. Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Edit: The error I am getting using `df.pivot(index=['Account', 'contract_date', 'item_id'], columns=['type'])`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
In [1660]: df.pivot(index=['Account', 'contract_date', 'item_id'], columns=['type'])
Out[1660]: 
                              quantity                 price                 tax             net_amount              
type                                 C       P       S     C       P      S    C     P     S          C      P      S
Account contract_date item_id                                                                                        
ABC123  2020-06-17    1370         NaN     NaN  5000.0   NaN     NaN  0.170  NaN   NaN  30.0        NaN    NaN  900.0
                      1409       500.0  1000.0  2000.0  0.25  0.3550  0.053  5.0  10.0  15.0      180.0  400.0  150.0
DEF456  2020-06-18    7214         NaN  3000.0     NaN   NaN  0.1793    NaN  NaN  20.0   NaN        NaN  600.0    NaN
```

Comment: My Pandas version is `1.1.0`. Can you try upgrading to that?

Comment: @MayankPorwal hi, after upgrading the pandas version, it is working as expected now. Thank you

Comment: Great!! Glad to help.